# Ionic 2, Storage, "keys()" doesn't update properly?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

I just started using learning Ionic 2 in hope of creating apps for personal use(I am very much a rookie). I have ran into a minor(but annoying) problem when creating a app for custom random generators.

The set up is a main "Random Generators" page with a ion-list of each individual "random generator". The random generators are stored as a key,value(NameOfGenerator, dataInJSON) pair in ionics suggested "Storage" module. So my idea was to get the names for the ion-list via the "keys()" function in Storage. This is updated by re-running the "keys()" command each time i add or remove a generator. It works well for removing but it does not automatically update for adding.

I have looked at the console output and it seems like the update-function(updateGenLst()) runs, but the "keys()" function doesn't seem to find the newly added key/value pair. However when I re-enter the page, the "keys()" function seem to find it via the constructor.

I did the following:

1. I enter the "Random Generators" page, via home page
2. I add "Test 3" as a new generator.
3. I go back to home page, and then into "Random Generators" page again
4. I remove "Test 3" from the list

Which gave this console output:

```
1. Found in storage Array [ "Test 1", "Test 2" ]  main.js:35706:13
2. Hello AddGenPage Page  main.js:96550:9
WARN Will-change memory consumption is too high. Budget limit is the document surface area multiplied by 3 (474002 px). Occurrences of will-change over the budget will be ignored.  localhost:8100
2. Updateded storage Array [ "Test 1", "Test 2" ]  main.js:35720:13
WARN Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.  localhost:8100
3. Found in storage Array [ "Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3" ]  main.js:35706:13
4. Removed undefined  main.js:35725:13
4. Updateded storage Array [ "Test 1", "Test 2" ]
```

Below I present both the javascript and html side of relevant code snipps from the page.

This is relevant parts of my page.ts file:

```
export class RandomGenerators {
    public generators = [];

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public modalCtrl: ModalController, public storage: Storage) {
        storage.keys().then((val) => {
            this.generators = val;
        })
    }

    ionViewDidLoad() {}

    updateGenLst() {
        this.storage.keys().then((val) => {
            this.generators = val;
            console.log('Updateded storage', val)
        })
    }

    rmGen(gen){
        this.storage.remove(gen).then((val) => {
        console.log('Removed ' + val + "");
        });
    this.updateGenLst();
   }

   addGen() {
       let addModal = this.modalCtrl.create(AddGenPage);

       addModal.onDidDismiss((gen) => {
           if(gen) {
               this.saveGen(gen);
               this.updateGenLst();
           }
       });
   addModal.present();
   }

   saveGen(gen){
       this.storage.set(gen.name,gen);
   }
```

Here are relevant parts from the html side:

```
....
<ion-buttons end>
    <button ion-button icon-only (click)="addGen()">
        <ion-icon name="add-circle"></ion-icon>
    </button>
</ion-buttons>
....
<ion-list>
  <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let gen of generators">
  <ion-item>
    {{gen}}
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item-options>
    <button danger (click)="rmGen(gen)"><ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon> Delete</button>
  </ion-item-options>
</ion-item-sliding>
  </ion-list>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print keys *after* updation, the guarenteed location is inside `then`.

For eg:

```
    rmGen(gen){
        this.storage.remove(gen).then((val) => {
        console.log('Removed ' + val + "");
        this.updateGenLst();//here
        });

   }
```

Also `this.storage.set` would also be returning a promise. So in your `addGen` function,

```
this.saveGen(gen).then((data)=>{//saveGen should return the storage.set call
           this.updateGenLst();
```

}

Comment: Ok, I got it to work. I just want to check that my reasoning is correct.

Since updateGenLst() requires storage.set() to have "finnished" I need to specifically code that, "do not run updateGenLst() until you finished with stoage.set(). And the way to do that is to use then.

Can I use then after any function, even functions I wrote myself? E.g. could I write updateGenLst().then()? Or would  I need to rewrite updateGenLst() so it has the "then()" functionallity?

Comment: Ok.. maybe you need to start here.. https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise.. The storage spi returns a promise of a response. The actual response will be received in then at a future time(async programming). to create a new promise of anything use `new Promise(resolve,reject)` or of a value : `Promise.of(val)`

Comment: Hope this explains it

Comment: It does, thank you. I am not sure I fully understand every part, but I feel like I get the general idea. 

(Sidenote: Is there somewhere I can ask about typos/minor problems in code? I think there is a typo when I am trying to add a new page in app_modules.ts(have added like 10 before without problems) but after several hours of trying to find the typo I am starting to feel hopeless.)

Comment: questions about general debugging may end up being closed..you will have to narrow it down to a specific problem to ask in SO..http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Good luck :)